# Pnp powershell script find propertyBag on SPO Hub Site -Assocated

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, pnp-powershell

Is there a way to find the properties of the site/web using Get-PnPPropertyBag by looping through a Hub site and associated sites?
Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key MyKey only for one site properties, but I would like to iterate through sites on SPO and get properties to output into a  CSV file..

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://mytenat-admin.sharepoint.us/" 

#Getting the hub site id for which we want to generate the report - those are connected to this hub site.
$hubSiteURL="https://mytenatgov.sharepoint.us/sites/TargetSite"
$hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $hubSiteURL  
$hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId
write-host " #####Generating sites connected a single hub site report######: " -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
write-host "Hub Site URL: " $hubSiteURL


$associatedSites = @()


#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {$oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 

  if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
  {

    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url

     $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject     
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "HubSiteURL" -value $hubSiteURL
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "HubSiteID" -value $hubSiteId
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $oneSite.Title
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "AssociatedStatus" -value $oneSite.Status



     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject

  }
}

#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **Get-PnPPropertyBag** command we will get the all property bag key and value from the tenant:

[image]

In the script we can add the below inside foreach loop

```
$propretyBagValue=Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key "vti_sitemasterid"     
    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url
    $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject

     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site URL" -value $oneHubSite.SiteUrl
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site ID" -value $oneHubSite.ID
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Associated Site URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Associated Site Status" -value $oneSite.Status
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Property Bag Value" -value $propretyBagValue     

     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject
```

The final script will look like below:

```
CLS    
$userName = "Global-sharepoint2019@globalsharepoint2019.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourPassWord"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred

#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {$oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url 

  if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
  {
       $propretyBagValue=Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key "vti_sitemasterid" 

    write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url
    $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject

     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site URL" -value $oneHubSite.SiteUrl
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Hub Site ID" -value $oneHubSite.ID
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Associated Site URL" -value $oneSite.Url
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Associated Site Status" -value $oneSite.Status
     $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Property Bag Value" -value $propretyBagValue     

     #Add the object with property to an Array
     $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject

  }
}     

}
#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
$associatedSites | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\GetAllSitesAssociatedInHubSites\SitesConnectedToHubSiteReprotForTenant.csv" -NoTypeInformation  
write-host "##### Generating master hub sites along with connected sites report for the tenant ends here ######:" -BackgroundColor DarkYellow

######The below script will list down all hub sites and their associated connected sites in the tenant - ends here##################
```

The propertybag value csv will look like below:

[image]

**Notes :**

- This is the default property bag value for the site master in my tenant... so if we have the custom propertybag value in the tenant, the will get the different key value results of Propertybag... in that case accordingly we need to pass the parameter in **Get-PnPPropretyBag** command.

Comment: For some reason it returned empty. is it because of my connection. I do have custom property.

Comment: It could be the connection issue.. try to debug connect-PnPOnline... and the account using which running this code, it should be SharePoint Administrator or global administrator right.

Comment: Yes, I am global admin, it only get the first site and connection stops

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell Script for your reference.

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://mytenat-admin.sharepoint.us/" -Credential $creds

#Getting the hub site id for which we want to generate the report - those are connected to this hub site.
$hubSiteURL="https://mytenatgov.sharepoint.us/sites/TargetSite"
$hubSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $hubSiteURL  
$hubSiteId = $hubSite.HubSiteId
write-host " #####Generating sites connected a single hub site report######: " -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
write-host "Hub Site URL: " $hubSiteURL

$associatedSites = @()

#Get all sites associated to the hub site(in the above hub site)
$sitesTenant = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed 
$sitesTenant | select url | % {
    $oneSite = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url
    if($oneSite.hubsiteid -eq $hubSiteId)
    {
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $oneSite.Url -Credential $creds
        $property=Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key 'MyKey'
        write-host "Associated Site URL: " $oneSite.url
        $assocatedSiteObject = New-Object PSObject     
        $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "HubSiteURL" -value $hubSiteURL
        $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "HubSiteID" -value $hubSiteId
        $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $oneSite.Title
        $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "URL" -value $oneSite.Url
        $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "AssociatedStatus" -value $oneSite.Status
        $assocatedSiteObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "MyProperty" -value $property
        #Add the object with property to an Array
        $associatedSites += $assocatedSiteObject
    }
}
#Export the site array collection to a CSV file
$associatedSites | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\HubSiteReprotForTenant.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I got the first site property, but then the powershell disconnect. I have more than 20+ sites i would like to get their properties. How should I make sure the ps connection keep running?

Comment: @Aby: Then inside the foreach loop of each sites , try to write the below connect command and see Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred

Comment: @HabiburRahaman Sitll no luck with admin site url

Comment: I wonder why this is happening.. my connection is stable... are you in VPN? As an alternate try to connect using appid and client secret

Comment: Like below :Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -AppId $appId -AppSecret $appSecret

Comment: And also please verify the account what you are using to connect is not MFA enabled.

Comment: Yes, I am vpn. It is MFA enabled I think. How can I verify that.